# Bounded wildcards in the class definition not working?

Tags: java

I am trying to make the following work:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public abstract class Thing implements Iterable<? extends Serializable> {}
```

But I compile and get the following error:

```
Thing.java:2: unexpected type
found   : ? extends java.io.Serializable
required: class or interface without bounds
public abstract class Thing extends Iterable<? extends Serializable> {}
```

I'm not sure why there is ambiguity here? Shouldn't the compiler know what I am intending? I'd love to be able to get this exact functionality if possible, and to understand why this doesn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `Iterable` is an interface, so is `Serializable`

Comment: Good catch, same error though.

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? What's your use case?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your intent is to have something like the following:

```
public class FooBar implements Iterable<? extends Serializable> {
    public Iterator<? extends Serializable> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }
}
```

However, this is functionally equivalent to having the generic parameter be just `Serializable`. Calling the `next` method on an `Iterator<? extends Serializable>` returns a `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.Iterable class definition

```
Iterable<T>
```

So it will always expect any **class** or **interface** to assign to genric parameter **T**

But you passed a bound type parameter which caused the error.

Comment: `Serializable` is an interface, you _can't_ inherit from it.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes you are right, actually I wrote that with some absent mind. Now I corrected it.

Comment: When's the last time you tried to define a generic class as `FooBar<? extends Type>`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Actually, Interface *can* inherit from another interface.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad That isn't the case in this example. This was a class definition inheriting from an interface, which in Java is impossible.